# Java/spring chats, slack for talking like https://symfony-devs.slack.com/ , not how to build a chat

Tags: java, spring

Please tell chats for talking. When I search in stackoverflow or google, I just find how to build a chat. Where are the chats for Spring or Java where you can ask question like https://symfony-devs.slack.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

One chat I remembered is

https://devcord.com/ - it has java channel.